# How to map back the values from $lookup to local array field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to map back the valuse from a `$lookup` operation to local array field.

Currently, I am only able to create a standalone array field using `$lookup`, but not able to map the value back inside the original array.

An example of document:

**Input**

```
User: 
{
  "_id": "58a4fa0e24180825b05e14e9"
  "events": [
    {"eventId": "100", "joined": ISODate("2019-10-04T04:25:44.636Z")}, 
    {"eventId": "1001", "joined": ISODate("2019-10-04T04:25:44.636Z")}, 
    {"eventId": "1002", "joined": ISODate("2019-10-04T04:25:44.636Z")}
}

Event: 
{
  "eventId": "100",
  "eventName": "Taco Day"
}
```

**Output I want:**

```
User:
{
  "_id": "58a4fa0e24180825b05e14e9"
  "events": [
    {"eventId": "100", "joined": ISODate("2019-10-04T04:25:44.636Z"), eventName: "Taco Day"}, 
    {"eventId": "1001", "joined": ISODate("2019-10-04T04:25:44.636Z")}, 
    {"eventId": "1002", "joined": ISODate("2019-10-04T04:25:44.636Z")}
}
```

Comment: Try https://mongoplayground.net/p/2D2_TNtfIVB

Comment: @sushantmehta That works! I see that you used the `$filter` inside a `$map`. What if I know that for each eventId in `User.events`, there must be a coresponding event in `Event` collection. Is there a way I can optimize the query?

Comment: There's no `$$index` variable inside `$map`. I am not able to eliminate the nested operation...